# What do the NYC Continental residents do when its deconsecrated?

Tags: john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

What do the NYC Continental residents do when its deconsecrated?
Aren't they informed? Do they never leave their rooms or look at Facebook?
Are they not aware of Wick traveling back to the Continental?

Comment: I'm not sure that they have a thing called facebook

Comment: They were informed it's getting closed for some made up reason. Some maybe knew what it really meant, but it's not like all of them were assassins.

Answer (score 1):

They're almost certainly informed of it. We've seen that there's a system in place to communicate information such as new bounties, assassins being declared excommunicado, the details of a bounty being modified, etc. to all members within a geographical area via phone number.

Given that information such as the NYC Continental being deconsecrated would be important for them to know, the same system would likely be used to broadcast it; it's possible we even see this happening in Chapter 3, but I don't recall.

What do they do when they find out? Probably leave. They could stay in their rooms, but that still puts them at risk of getting caught up in the gunfight (assuming that deconsecration is only used in extreme cases, a display of force is likely always the next step). Finding somewhere else to stay while the situation is dealt with is the sensible course of action.

Comment: I might be remembering the wrong part, but wasn't there a scene with the guests in the lobby of the Continental all getting messages through and they checked their phones?

Comment: @Anthony  Right. If they're informed why doesn't chaos ensue. Why would they not all go after Wick?  Why doesn't Winston even offer an explanation? Why wouldn't even Continental employees get involved such as the super cool sommelier guy from Wick 2 (Peter Serafinowicz).

Comment: @RandyZeitman i think a part of it is that not everyone that's under the table is an assassin.  so they stay at the continental cause it's assumed safe.  once it's no longer safe they abandon ship to another safe haven

Comment: @DForck42  Right! ... did you see such a mass exit? ... or that they ever even informed?... or that several decided to team up and go after Wick for the $14M?